# How to enable magnifier on iPad in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-view, zoom

I want to enable magnifier in iPad device, this is my `view.xml` code:

```
<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
   <var name="top">53</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
   <var name="left">790</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
   <var name="width">412</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
   <var name="height">338</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
   <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
   <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

It working fine in desktop, but i want this in iPad device as well, **How can i do it in ipad.?**